# как в ubuntu сделать root доступ?

Tags: ubuntu

Такой вопрос у меня есть документ, который я могу редактировать только имея доступ. Если я его просто открываю в редакторе, что то меняю и сохраняю, то он мне пишет, что ты не можешь ничего менять. Но когда я через терминал открываю этот документ и пишу sudo то снова открывается редактор я вношу свои изменения и нормально все сохраняется. Так вот вопрос в том как сделать так чтоб я не использую терминал мог просто открыть в редакторе документ и потом нормально его сохранить не получая уведомление о том, что у меня нет доступа...

Comment: В каком редакторе? В целом, можно настроить запуск `nautilus` (стандартный графический файловый менеджер Ubuntu) от рута.

Comment: добавьте в вопрос вывод команды `ls -hal document_name`. И уточните, что за документ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Алексей, добрый день.

Достаточно сменить права на данный документ. Как сделать и какие права установить можно в статье: http://ubuntulinux.ru/config/recipe/izmenit-prava-na-fajly-ili-papki-v-linux/

Если все же остались вопросы то надо выполнить команду sudo chmod 777 /media/share/file.txt в это случае указанный файл смогут читать, редактировать и запускать все пользователи системы.

Comment: Далеко не во всех случаях можно прямо так взять и выставить права `777`. Многие сервисы просто откажутся запускаться, если вы на их конфиги выставите такое.

Comment: Я так понял, что нет такой возможности "получить доступ ко всем файлам как root" без возможных побочных эффектов. Лучше всего с такими документами работать через консоль с помощью команды 'sudo', верно?

Comment: Nick, вы правы. Все зависит от того, что наш коллега хочет изменять.

Comment: Алексей, такая возможность есть, но она черевата последствиями. Если вы говорите о каких-либо конфигах, то лучше всего с ними работать через 'sudo'. Если вы говорите о документах типа Word, Excel, etc. то проще им дать доступ 'для всех' и нормально с ними работать.